# File name without extension in bash for loop

Tags: bash

In a for loop like this one:

```
for f in `ls *.avi`; do echo $f; ffmpeg -i $f $f.mp3; done
```

$f will be the complete filename, including the extension. For example, for song1.avi the output of the command will be song1.avi.mp3. Is there a way to get only song1, without the .avi from the for loop?

I imagine there are ways to do that using awk or other such tools, but I'm hoping there's something more straight forward.

Thanks

Comment: As an aside, you want to lose the Useless Use of Backticks.  The correct and idiomatic syntax is `for f in *.avi; do ...`

Comment: Not to mention - if you have spaces in the filenames (though this is an evil practice), you actually should go like `ls *avi | while read f; do (...); done`. And then quote `"$f"` everywhere. Just saying.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Use bash parameter expansion

```
${f%%.*}
```

Note that you need the greedy version because there are multiple dots in the file name.

From bash manual:

> **${parameter%word}**
>
> **${parameter%%word}**
>
> The word is expanded to produce a pattern just as in filename expansion. If the pattern matches a trailing portion of the expanded value of parameter, then the result of the expansion is the value of parameter with the shortest matching pattern (the ‘%’ case) or the longest matching pattern (the ‘%%’ case) deleted. If parameter is ‘@’ or ‘*’, the pattern removal operation is applied to each positional parameter in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list. If parameter is an array variable subscripted with ‘@’ or ‘*’, the pattern removal operation is applied to each member of the array in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.

Comment: Use `${f%.*}` -- if you use `${f%%.*}` and $f is "one.two.avi", you'll get "one" instead of "one.two"

Answer (score 24):

This should do it:

```
for i in *.m4a; do
  ffmpeg -i $i ${i%%.*}.mp3
done
```

Comment: For a known extension (like in the `for` list), you can use `basename $i .m4a` (in backticks), but once you memorize the `%.*` (one percent is, arguably, better), you won't look back again.

Comment: This is a bit buggy due to lack of quotes. Making it `ffmpeg -i "$i" "${i%%.*}.mp3"` will fix support for filenames with spaces. (BTW, these are issues that http://shellcheck.net/ can catch).

Answer (score 0):

I combined the code sample from https://stackoverflow.com/a/8077421/340175 (which applies the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/7119316/340175) and Charles Duffy's comment (which I can't find a way to link to directly) to get:

`for i in *.png; do img2pdf  "$i" --out "${i%.*}.pdf";done`

And yes, I do have lots of filenames with spaces in them, the quotation marks enabled the command to process those files too. I wanted to convert image files to pdf equivalents to keep latex compilations from taking too long.